# Nuxt 3 / nuxt-image [h3] Implicit event handler conversion is deprecated. Use eventHandler() or fromNodeMiddleware() to define event handlers

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm planning using Nuxt 3 to build SSR website. I'm using nuxt-image to handle all images under static directory. I wonder that nuxt-image doesn't work well but I don't know how to resolve. Just to be clear, please see my steps below.

My project directories:

```
components
pages
static/
    sample-image.webp
app.vue
nuxt.config.ts
package.json
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "build": "nuxt build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.7.1"
}
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        "@nuxt/image",
    ]
})
```

**MyImage.vue** component:

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
    <div>
        <NuxtImg
            format="webp"
            src="/sample-image.webp"
            loading="lazy"
            alt="Sample Image"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

I got this warning at **yarn dev**.

```
WARN  [h3] Implicit event handler conversion is deprecated. Use eventHandler() or fromNodeMiddleware() to define event handlers. 
Route: /_ipx 
Handler: function IPXMiddleware(req, res) {
    return handleRequest({ url: req.url, headers: req.headers }, ipx).then((_res) => {
        res.statusCode = _res.statusCode;
        res.statusMessage = _res.statusMessage;
        for (const name in _res.headers) {
            res.setHeader(name, _res.headers[name]);
        }
        res.end(_res.body);
    });
}
```

Then I'm facing an error 500 when accesscing **http://localhost:3000**

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')
```

Hope anyone will assist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **Nuxt2** `nuxt-image` module. Try removing it and using [this nuxt-image (for Nuxt 3) package](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/get-started)

Comment: Ok, I used ```"@nuxt/image-edge": "^1.0.0-27769790.4b27db3"``` and it was solved only in development mode. Another problem occurs when it's in build/production mode. The image didn't show up. My setting in ```nuxt.config.js``` is ```image: { domains: ['http://localhost:3000'], dir: 'assets/images' }```. I stored all images source under ```assets/images``` directory, not  ```static```. The url was ```<img src="/_ipx/f_webp/sample-image.png" />```

Comment: @mrale81 Images stored under `/assets` are bundled with webpack. I don't think vue image is gonna work well with that. First, move your images under `/public`. As the `ipx` provider is configured by default, you don't need the `image: { domains ....` stuff in your config file. Lastly replace your `img` tag with the nuxt-image one : `<nuxt-img src="/myAsset.png" />` with `myAsset` being the name of your asset, stored under public.